# Cant generate 301 redirection using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following redirection in htacces

```
Redirect 301 /xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.html https://xxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyy/zzzzzzzzzzzz.html
```

well this one works properly, however if i try adding more redirections using the same method they dont work, the only difference is that those links does not have .html extension.

```
Redirect 301 /xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx https://xxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyy/zzzzzzzzzzzz
```

Example:
I have the following url https://estetic4you.com/product/index?brand=Mesoestetic which returns an 404 error, so i use the following code: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/product/index?brand=Mesoestetic$ estetic4you.com/14-mesoestetic` but still not redirecting. I also tried:

```
Redirect 301 /product/index?brand=Mesoestetic https://www.estetic4you.com/14-mesoestetic
```

and it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

You cannot match query string using `Redirect` directive.

Use `mod_rewrite` engine with a separate `RewriteCond` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} brand=Mesoestetic
RewriteRule ^product/index/?$ https://www.estetic4you.com/14-mesoestetic? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: it still does not redirect. I will show you the exact problem. PD: im editing the message... I have the following url http://www.estetic4you.com/product/index?brand=Mesoestetic which returns an 404 error, so i use the following code: RedirectMatch 301 ^/product/index?brand=Mesoestetic$ https://www.estetic4you.com/14-mesoestetic but still not redirecting

Comment: No, You cannot match query string using `RedirectMatch`. Edit the question with this example so that I can update my answer.

Comment: no, it doesnt work, still not redirecting, im in the same situation, i only was able to redirect one link, of a specific page (product in prestashop) which ended in .html. However the rest of the links arent redirected

Comment: What is the **full URL** you're entering in the browser that is not redirecting?